# zf2 table valued function as tablegateway/table

Tags: zend-framework2, user-defined-functions

How can I use a table valued function like

```
select * from pv_my_table_valued_function(1)
```

"pv_my_table_valued_function(?)" as table for my tablegateway

for instance the normal instantiation would be:

```
'Application\Model\MyTable' =>  function($sm) {
     $tableGateway = $sm->get('MyTableGateway');
     $table = new MyTable($tableGateway);
     return $table;
},
'MyTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
      $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
      $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
      $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new MyTableEntity());
      return new TableGateway('my_table', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
},
```

Can i do the same like for instance:

```
'MyTableValuedGateway' => function ($sm) {
          $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
          $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
          $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new MyTableValued());
          return new TableGateway('pv_my_table_valued_function(?)', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
    },
```

Or any other ideas how to do that instead of casting the Select object later on to a string and replace the table name?

**Edit:**

As a quick basic example of how I use the tableGateway later on:
In my Model MyTable.php

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    // I already initialized the tableGateway via Dependecy Injection in 
    // a __construct() in an abstract class
    $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();

    // some sql stuff
    $select->where(...);
    $select->order(...);

    // now it gets tricky.. what I normally do is known
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);

    // what I need to do when using my table valued function is like
    $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
    $platform = $adapter->getPlatform();
    $sqlStr = $select->getSqlString($platform);

    $select = str_replace('FROM [my_table]', "FROM pv_my_table_valued_function({$this->my_special_parameter}) AS my_pv", $sqlStr);

    $resultSet = $adapter->query($select, array());

    return $resultSet;
}
```

So how could i "stay" with the Select object but kind of somehow passing that parameter through with a wildcard?

Hope this makes it more clear

Comment: Where does your table name comes from?

Comment: Well, it's a table valued function built with MS SQL, this is just the initiating process, I use a model where i call the method $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
It works fine with normal tables or views of course.. but with those, where i want to pass a parameter through, it is getting hard to initiate, when making a str_replace() later on its too hacky and not beautiful as we need it more often

Comment: @Marcel i edited my post, thanks for your answers anyways, but I think this might make you more understand what im struggling with

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the constructor of the `Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway` class, you 'll find out that this class takes the table name as the first parameter.

Let 's guess, that your table name comes from a GET parameter called table. So a factory could look like the following example.

```
namespace Application\Db\TableGateway\Factory;

class MyDynamicTableFactory 
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        // bc zf2 (remove when using zf3)
        $serviceLocator = $container->getServiceLocator();

        // table name from get parameter
        $router = $serviceLocator->get('router');
        $request = $serviceLocator->get('request');
        $match = $router->match($request);

        $table = $match->getParam('table');

        // adapter
        $adapter = $serviceLocator->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

        // resultset
        $resultset = new HydratingResultset(
            new ClassMethods(),
            new YourDynamicTableEntity()
        );

        // table gateway
        $gateway = new TableGateway($table, $adapter, null, $resultset);

        return $gateway;
    }
}
```

For your purpose a factory is the best solution. Even if your table name comes from another source than a GET parameter, you are able to do it in a factory. Just instantiate another class, which will give you your table name.

Just write your factory in your service config in `module.config.php` file as follows ...

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'MyDynamicTable' => MyDynamicTableFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

With this notation you are able to get your dynamic table gateway everywhere, where the service locator is available. Keep in mind, that you should not call the service locator in a controller. Just pass it via dependency injection or use factories for every class you need.

Example call for your table gateway in a factory

```
$gateway = $serviceLocator->get('MyDynamicTable');
```

To keep it short: use a factory instead of a anonymous function for keeping it clean and simple. Regardless of whether a factory or an anonymous function the call of the table gateway takes your table name as parameter in the constructor. So just get your table name from anywhere and pass it as a parameter.